# The number of elements in an array using pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So while studying for my exams I was trying to do a practice problem for pointers.

In the following code I'm trying to **display the number of elements before the first occurrence of 0.**

There is only one part that i didn't understand please see the 6th last line.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << "Please enter number " << i + 1 << " in the array: ";
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    int *Aptr = A;
    while(*Aptr !=0){
        cout << *Aptr << "";
        Aptr++;
    }
    cout << "\nThere are " << (Aptr - A)  //Here is what i don't understand.
    << " numbers before the first occurrence of 0." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So why exactly is **(Aptr - A)** giving me the number of elements instead of a memory location, and why is this even doable since **Aptr** is a pointer and **A** is an array?

Can someone explain to me in detail?

Comment: An array and a pointer are not so different as they might seem.

Comment: also A is pointer that points to  A[0]

Comment: See [C++ pointer arithmetic](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_arithmatic.htm).

Comment: What if the user entered 10 non-zero integers?

Answer (score 4):

When used in an expression, like `Aptr - A`, the name of an array `A` will be implicitly converted to a pointer (equal to `&A[0]`).

Then the compiler is faced with subtracting two pointers of the same type (both of type `int *` in your case).   That is specified as giving a value of type `std::ptrdiff_t`, which is, in turn "a signed integral type able to represent the result of subtracting two pointers".

Pointer arithmetic, when subtracting two pointers of type `int`  (i.e. two `int *`s) gives the number of `int`s between the two pointers   (assuming they are in the same object, which is true in this case, since `Aptr` points at an element of the array `A`).

Practically, if `Aptr` is equal to `&A[i]`, the subtraction `Aptr - &A[0]` gives a `std::ptrdiff_t` equal to `i`.

Note:  there is another problem in your code, as since the first (`for`) loop reads `10` values, while the second `while` loop keeps incrementing `Aptr` until it points at an `int` with value `0`.    If the user enters any zero values, the second loop will stop when it finds the first (even if the user enters non-zero elements after that).     If the user enters no values equal to `0`, then the `while` loop has undefined behaviour, since `Aptr` will keep walking through memory past the end of `A` until it happens to find memory that compares (as an `int`) equal to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, name of array `A` is associated to address of (pointer at) the first item in the array.

> So why exactly is (Aptr - A) giving me the number of elements?

Because according to rules address arithmetic subtraction operation (also `+`, and similar) is performed based on the data type.

I mean, that compiler operating with `int*` makes `++`, `--`, addition, subtraction an integer, etc. adds addresses needed for shifting to next/previous item.

If you really want to see how many bytes are located between addresses, just convert addresses to `int` before making subtraction:

```
 cout << endl << "Address difference is " << int(Aptr) - int(A) << endl;
```

You can try that with different data types as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A[5];
    short B[5];
    unsigned char C[5];
    cout << "Array (data type) | Syze of array | Size of item | Item distanse | Bytes distance" << endl;
    cout << "A (int)           :" << setw(10) 
                            << sizeof(A) << setw(15)
                            << sizeof(A[0]) << setw(15) 
                            << &A[4] - A << setw(15) 
                            << int(&A[4]) - int(A) << endl;
    cout << "B (short)         :" << setw(10) 
                            << sizeof(B) << setw(15)
                            << sizeof(B[0]) << setw(15) 
                            << &B[4] - B << setw(15) 
                            << int(&B[4]) - int(B) << endl;
    cout << "C (un.char)       :" << setw(10)
                            << sizeof(C) << setw(15)
                            << sizeof(C[0]) << setw(15)
                            << &C[4] - C << setw(15)
                            << int(&C[4]) - int(C) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

To be better prepared for your exam, consider the following example with pointers:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A[5] = {0}; // all items now are 0
    int * P = A + 2; // the same as P = &A[2];
    *P = 33; // writing to item A[2];
    cout << A[2] << endl; // just to check in usual way
    cout << *(A + 2) << endl; // using A as a pointer
    cout << *(2 + A) << endl; // almost the same to previous
    cout << 2[A] << endl; // quite strange, but it works
    cout << 0[P] << endl; // and this is the same
    return 0;
}
```

You must understand that `0[P]` means for compiler `*(0 + P)`, as well as `2[A]` means - `*(2 + A)`, but you should not write in your program in such style (exceptions are only cases when you want to confuse a reader).

And one more important thing - difference between array and pointer - are shown in the following example:

```cpp
    int A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *P = A;
    cout << "A = " << A << endl;
    cout << "P = " << P << endl;
    cout << "size of A = " << sizeof(A) << endl;
    cout << "size of P = " << sizeof(P) << endl;
```

even if the addresses (vaules A and P) are equal, compiler works with array (`A`) in a different way than with pointer: `sizeof(A)` means memory allocated for whole array (5 items of `sizeof(int)` each), but `sizeof(P)` means memory allocated for data type `int *` (pointer to int). So, `sizeof(P)` depends only on compiler and OS platform (e.g. pointer can be 32-bit or 64-bit), but `sizeof(A)` depends on size of item (`int` may be not 32 bits) and NUMBER OF ITEMS in the array.

And you can "go to the next item" with pointer:

```
  P++;
  cout << *P << endl;
```

but you are not able to do:

```
  A++;
```

because `A` is not variable of pointer type (it is just similar in sense of "address of the first item"), and compiler will say you something like:

> error : '++' needs l-value